# What is this decorator looking comment in javascript

Tags: javascript, syntax, comments

just saw this code in an open source app can someone tell me what is this?

[image]

removing this doesnt change anything and i tried searching google and this is what google says

> The @description tag allows you to provide a general description of the symbol you are documenting. The description may include HTML markup. It may also include Markdown formatting if the Markdown plugin is enabled.

what HTML? this is backend code

Comment: Please replace images of code with a text-based [mcve]

Comment: The highlighted comments in the image look like [JSDoc comments](https://jsdoc.app/). You can add markdown and HTML to better format the descriptions.

Comment: https://jsdoc.app/about-getting-started